# How many type of video format supported in native android device?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat, video

Basically i refer the android developer site and also search on google but did not find any proper solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic supported video format are

3GPP (.3gp)

MPEG-4 (.mp4)

WebM (.webm)

Matroska (.mkv, Android 4.0+)

[More Information on Developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#video-formats)

Answer (score 3):

Android Supported Video Format/Codec

1. H.263
2. H.264 AVC
3. MPEG-4 SP
4. VP8

   Supported Video File Types/Container Formats

   - H.263 >               • 3GPP (.3gp)

     • MPEG-4 (.mp4)
   - H.264 AVC >      • 3GPP (.3gp)

     • MPEG-4 (.mp4)

     • MPEG-TS (.ts, AAC audio only, not seekable, Android 3.0+)
   - MPEG-4 SP >     •3GPP (.3gp)
   - VP8 >                 • WebM (.webm)

     • Matroska (.mkv, Android 4.0+)